# ListView not showing data from ViewModel when ViewModel gets initialised in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and I'm still a bit confused how the binding works. Basically I have a list that does not get refreshed if I re-initialise the `ViewModel`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ViewModels:MyViewModel x:Key="myViewModel"/>

<!-- ... -->

<ListView x:Name="MyList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
          DataContext="{StaticResource myViewModel}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
          DockPanel.Dock="Top">
```

When the `Window` loads for the first time, the `ViewModel` gets called and fetches the data from the database. Fine, up to here.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> Customers { get; set; }

    public int HasWarnigs
    {
        get { return Customers.Where(a => a.HasWarning == true).Count(); }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        // fetch data.
        Customers = ...
    }
}
```

I have a method on the view that initialises the `ViewModel` again, to reload new data from the database:

```
vm = new MyViewModel();
```

However, the new data won't be displayed automatically in the `ListView` unless I specify the `DataContext` of the `ListView`, in code behind, after initialising the `ViewModel` again.

```
vm = new AnswersViewModel();
MyListView.DataContext = vm;
```

I'm a bit confused I have to explicitly set the `DataContext` as I thought specifying the `ViewModel` in the xaml file, under the window's resources, would cause the data to be bound to the view model every time it gets initialised?

Thanks!

Comment: You create a new, entirely separate, instance of `MyViewModel`, which has zero connection to the first one. Why would the first instance get magically replaced by the second?

Comment: Are you implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) in your view model?

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` isn't necessary if the view model contains only `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Thanks!  _"Why would the first instance get magically replaced by the second?"_ :) 
so how do I do to requery the ViewModel and to show the data? Do I need to assign the DataContext or there is another way without creating a new instance of the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a object `vm1` is created and put in the data context of the view.
When `vm1` is put in the data context of the view, then the view is binding to `vm1`.

When the data is refreshed, a object `vm2` is created with the refreshed data.
But the view is binding with the data of `vm1`, then the view display the old data of `vm1`.

When `vm2` is put in the data context of the view, then the view is binding to `vm2` and the view display the refreshed data of `vm2`.

As @canton7 say in comment, without good reason, it's better to update data in `vm1` to update the view.
In MVVM, you link (put in data context) the View with the ViewModel and only work with the ViewModel.